# How to force being clicked on the button "General Data"?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the example of my project:

[https://codepen.io/adan96/pen/ExaRgOe][1]

As You can see, I have got three button in my html code. The first if them should be clicked each time when I refresh the page or open the project after some time.

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="basicData1">
    <div id="createMaterialHeader">
      <h2><i><b>Create Material</b></i></h2>
      <div id="createMaterialOptions">
        <p>Additional Data</p>
        <p>Org. Level</p>
        <p>Check Screen Data</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'generalData')"><b>General Data</b></button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'materialData')"><b>Paris</b></button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Tokyo')"><b>Tokyo</b></button>
    </div>
    <div id="generalData" class="tabcontent">
      <form>
        <label for="employeeID">Employee ID: </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="employeeID" id="employeeID" readonly><br>
        <hr>
        <label for="requestNo">Request Number: </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="requestNo" id="requestNo" readonly><br>
        <label for="requestedBy">Requested By: </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="requestedBy" id="requestedBy" readonly><br>
        <label for="requestDate">Request Date: </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="requestDate" id="requestDate" readonly><br>
        <hr>
        <label for="eskNumber">(E)SK Number: </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="eskNumber" id="eskNumber" required><br>
        <hr>
        <label for="requestType">Request Type: </label><br>
          <select id="requestTypeSelection">
            <option value="creation">CREATION</option>
            <option value="extension">EXTENSION</option>
            <option value="modification">MODIFICATION</option>
          </select><br>
        <label for="requestSubtype">Request Subtype: </label><br>
          <select id="requestSubtypeSelection">
            <option value="hawaAndZpla">HAWA/ZPLA</option>
            <option value="newBatch">NEW BATCH</option>
            <option value="zplaToHawa">ZPLA>HAWA</option>
            <option value="dien">DIEN</option>
          </select>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="materialData" class="tabcontent">
      <form>
        <label for="productNumber">Product Number: </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="productNumber" id="productNumber" required><br>
        <label for="materialName">Material Name: </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="materialName" id="materialName" required><br>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Tokyo</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And JS code, which includes window.onload function needed to do it:

```
document.getElementById("requestTypeSelection").selectedIndex = -1;
document.getElementById("requestSubtypeSelection").selectedIndex = -1;

function openTab(evt, tabName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("generalData").onclick = document.getElementById("generalData").style.display = "block";
}
```

The main idea is to have General Data button always clicked (selecte etc.) after refreshing the page. Would You give me advice what to correct in JS code?

Answer (score 1):

Look is this doesn't solve your problem:

```
window.onload = () => {
    document.getElementById("generalData").style.display = "block"
.
.
.
}
```

You don't have to simulate the click of a button, you just have to trigger its action

Comment: ok I added event.currentTarget.className += " active"; to the code above and now it works :)

Comment: Perfect, I'm glad for it. Don't forget to evaluate and close the question, see ya :)